Material Design Color Utilities generating unexpected colors with Material Web Components
I am working on a project where I use the Material Design Color Utilities package to create a dynamic color theme based on a primary color. However, I have noticed that the generated colors are not as expected.
Here is my current code:
import { argbFromHex, hexFromArgb, TonalPalette, themeFromSourceColor, applyTheme, Theme } from "@material/material-color-utilities";

const baseColors = {
  primary: '#000000',
  secondary: '#FCE800',
  tertiary: '#00BFFF',
  error: '#F00F3E',
  neutral: '#6F7B80',
  neutralVariant: '#7B7768'
};

const createTheme = (): Theme => {
  const primaryArgb = argbFromHex(baseColors['primary']);
  const secondaryArgb = argbFromHex(baseColors['secondary']);
  const tertiaryArgb = argbFromHex(baseColors['tertiary']);
  const errorArgb = argbFromHex(baseColors['error']);
  const neutralArgb = argbFromHex(baseColors['neutral']);
  const neutralVariantArgb = argbFromHex(baseColors['neutralVariant']);

  const theme = themeFromSourceColor(primaryArgb);

  return {
    source: primaryArgb,
    schemes: theme.schemes,
    palettes: {
      primary: TonalPalette.fromInt(primaryArgb),
      secondary: TonalPalette.fromInt(secondaryArgb),
      tertiary: TonalPalette.fromInt(tertiaryArgb),
      neutral: TonalPalette.fromInt(neutralArgb),
      neutralVariant: TonalPalette.fromInt(neutralVariantArgb),
      error: TonalPalette.fromInt(errorArgb),
    },
    customColors: [],
  };
};
/*Overwrite mui system colors*/
const applyThemeVars = (root: HTMLElement, isDarkMode: boolean, theme: any) => {
  const style = root.style;
  const colors = isDarkMode ? theme.schemes.dark : theme.schemes.light;
  Object.entries(colors.props).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const hexColor = hexFromArgb(value as number);
    style.setProperty(`--md-sys-color-${key}`, hexColor);
  });
};

const applyCustomTheme = (isDarkMode: boolean) => {
  const generatedTheme = createTheme();
  applyThemeVars(document.documentElement, isDarkMode, generatedTheme);
  applyTheme(generatedTheme, { target: document.documentElement, dark: isDarkMode });
};

export const ThemeHelper = () => {
  return {
    applyCustomTheme,
  };
};

const themeHelper = ThemeHelper();
export default themeHelper;

I am using themeFromSourceColor to generate my theme based on the primary color (#000000). However, I get a primary color that is dark violet (#984061) instead of black (#000000).
Packages:
https://github.com/material-components/material-web#readme
https://github.com/material-foundation/material-color-utilities
Question:
Why is themeFromSourceColor generating a dark violet color instead of black? How can I ensure that the generated primary color exactly matches my specified color?

There are multiple issues in your question

You are using the "source colour" (#000000) but not a "primary color"
to generate a theme
You cannot ensure that the generated primary color exactly matches your specified color and should not be expecting this

Answering your first question:

After a number of calculations library creates a TonalPalette
based on the source color
Then it picks from the palette tone(50) color for light
theme as a primary color
For more details you can explore source code https://github.com/material-foundation/material-color-utilities/blob/main/typescript/utils/theme_utils.ts#L77

